# can we pass object of a class in different class constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor

I am a beginner in C++ and badly stuck at creating a constructor of a class that uses the object of another class. while doing so I am getting the error

> No matching function for call to ....

```
Priority_que::Priority_que(graph g) {
    for (unsigned i=0; i<g.size(); i++) {
        for (unsigned j=i; j<g.size(); j++) {
            g1[i][j] = g.getnode(i)(j) ; }
    }
```

here Priority_que is a class that uses the graph class object in its constructor.
please treat me as innocent if I am talking nonsense.

**EDIT** :
I am adding the class Priority_que and its constructor, hope this will help.

```
class Prio_que: public graph {
    public:
        Prio_que(graph);
        pair<int,int> minValue() ;  
        priority_queue<pair<int,int>, vector<pair<int,int>>, greater<pair<int,int>>> arranged ; 
        void dijkstra() ;
        int size() ;
    private:
        vector<vector<int>> g1 ;
        vector<int> parent ;
        vector<int> dist ;
        vector<bool> processed ;
        vector<pair<int,int>> dist_pair ;
};

Prio_que::Prio_que(graph g) {
    for (int i=0; i<g.size(); i++) {
        for (int j=i; j<g.size(); j++) {
            g1[i][j] = g.getnode(i,j) ; }
    }       
    parent(g.size(),-1);    //Stores Shortest Path Structure
    dist(g.size(),MAX); //Keeps shortest path values to each vertex from source
    processed(g.size(),false) ; //TRUE->Vertex is processed
    dist_pair(g.size(), make_pair(MAX, 0)) ; }
```

now the error is showing from parent(g.size(),-1); to the last line.

> No matching function for call to ....

Comment: This part of the code looks ok, the problem is elsewhere. You need to give us a piece of code that we can actually compile and see the same error as you, aka a [mcve] (don't dump all your code at us though, read the link first).

Comment: You can pass one object as an argument to a constructor of another.   If passing by value - as you are - the full definition of the `struct`/`class` being passed (`graph` in your case) must be visible to the compiler  (e.g. the header that defines the type being passed must already have been included).   Just passing a class that is defined in another source file won't work.

Comment: That element by element copy seems a good candidate to be part of the `graph` class. Consider `std::size_t` instead of `unsigned`, use `++i` instead `i++` in for loops.

Comment: @Peter no the function is defined in the same file. what does it mean by "No matching function for call to ...."  This error is frustrating me.. and also if there is any useful link to the C++ course you know please share.

Comment: By writing just *No matching function for call to ....* you are omitting the most relevant part of the error message.

Comment: @NikhilSahare - The function must be declared BEFORE (above) the point where it is used.  A definition of the function later in the same source file is insufficient - and from info you initially provided, that was the most obvious possibility.    In any event (now that you have edited to provide more code) the problem is that you are trying to initialise the member `parent` in the constructor body - which the compiler sees as a function call, not initialisation of a member.   You need to do the initialisations in the constructors *initialiser list* NOT in the function body.

Comment: @Peter Thank you very much for the detailed explanation. Now I understood this more clearly. It has really forced me to understand the basics first and then only apply them to problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are member variables and need to be initialized in the initializer list - you're trying to call them as functions, which is the reason for the error message.
You should also make the parameter a const reference to avoid copying it.

```
Prio_que::Prio_que(const graph& g)
    : parent(g.size(),-1),
      dist(g.size(),MAX),
      processed(g.size(),false),
      dist_pair(g.size(), make_pair(MAX, 0))
{
    for (int i=0; i<g.size(); i++) 
    {
        for (int j=i; j<g.size(); j++) 
        {
            g1[i][j] = g.getnode(i,j) ; 
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot brother for writing the rectified code. Now I will take care of it in future coding.

Comment: Note that `g1`, and its elements, need to be initialised (with correct sizes) before that loop in the constructor body is entered.    By default, `g1` will have zero size, so `g1[i][j]` gives undefined behaviour (and it will NOT resize if needed).    The resizing can be done in the initialiser list  (e.g.  `g1(g.size(), std::vector<int>(g1.size()))`) or explicitly in the constructor body (e.g. resize `g1` then resize all its elements).